# How do I include jQuery/bootstrap/javascript in my rails app with a CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I know you can add jQuery and bootstrap with gems, assets, and the application.css and application.js file. However, I would like to be able to add these files through a CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"             href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I have added the above into my application.html.erb file, but I seem to not be able to use bootstrap or jQuery still. Can you please explain why rails doesn't allow linking in the html file? Why must we use gems?

Comment: That is a CDN. https://maxCDN.bootstrapCDN.com - I don't think they are lying. Alternatively you could place the files on a CDN of your choosing and load it from there.

Comment: Yes but the CDN is not working. There is no effect on the rails app. Does rails allow CDNs in the html files or must I use gems and require that js file in the application.js?

Comment: I just tried it and it is now working again. I'm a little confused but thanks so much!

Comment: Look at the answer below. Are you not seeing any bootstrap files included? View the source of your app from a browser and make sure it's not loading.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the **js** file before the closing **body** tag as well:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to make sure you call your Jquery before your bootstrap files

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If you want to do a cdn call back for both Jquery and Bootstrap these are the links: [stackoverflow - Bootstrap cdn callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748112/load-local-bootstrap-css-and-js-if-load-fail-from-remote) and [stackoverflow - Jquery cdn callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jquery cdn](https://github.com/ai/jquery-cdn/blob/master/README.md) gem

In your layout,

```
<%= include_jquery cdn: :google %>
```